# Distance between two measures

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Suppose we have (practically infinite number of) i.i.d. samples from two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$, not necessarily having a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is there a way to use those samples to calculate some distance, say Wasserstein, between the two measures ?